# How to use Fubini's theorem?

Tags: probability, analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

For two stochastic processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$, if we have $\int_0^t E X_t^2dt<\infty$ and $\int_0^t E Y_t^2dt<\infty$. How to show that
$$
E\int_0^tX_tY_tdt=\int_0^tE[X_tY_t]dt
$$
from Fubini's theorem?

The condition of  Fubini's theorem is that
$$
\int_X\int_Y|f(x,y)|d\mu(x)d\mu(y)<\infty
$$
In our setting, this is
$$
\int_0^t\int_0^tX_tY_tdtdt<\infty.
$$
But how to show that? Does it seem that follows from Cauchy–Schwarz inequality?

Comment: It is not integrating $t$ twice. It is integrating on $t$ once then integrating on $\Omega$.

Comment: @Yuval Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Yuval said, the condition you want to check is not
$$\int_0^t\int_0^tX_tY_tdtdt<\infty $$
(Which actually doesn't make sense) but rather
$$\color{red}{\int_{\omega\in\Omega}}\int_0^t|X_t(\omega)Y_t(\omega)|dt\color{red}{d\mathbb P(\omega)}\left(=\mathbb E\int_0^tX_tY_tdt\right)<\infty.\tag1 $$
If you are not sure of what that means, check out the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Arbitrary_random_variables).

Let's prove that condition $(1)$ is satisfied : thanks to [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) we have that
$$\left(\int_0^t|X_tY_t|dt\right)^2 \le \left(\int_0^tX_t^2dt\right)\left(\int_0^tY_t^2dt\right) $$
Which implies, assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, that
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_0^t|X_tY_t|dt\right)^2\right] &\le\mathbb E\left[ \left(\int_0^tX_t^2dt\right)\left(\int_0^tY_t^2dt\right)\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[ \int_0^tX_t^2dt\right]\mathbb E\left[\int_0^tY_t^2dt\right]\\
&=\left(\int_0^t\mathbb E X_t^2dt\right)\left(\int_0^t\mathbb EY_t^2dt\right)\tag{*}\\
&<\infty\end{align}$$
(*Remark* : Note that in $(*)$, I applied Fubini's theorem to $X_t^2$ and $Y_t^2$ respectively, which is legit since by assumption the relevant integrals are finite.)

Lastly, by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), we have
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E\left[\int_0^t|X_tY_t|dt\right]&= \mathbb E\left[\sqrt{\left(\int_0^t|X_tY_t|dt\right)^2}\right]\\
&\le \sqrt{\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_0^t|X_tY_t|dt\right)^2\right]}\\
&<\infty\end{align} $$
Which means that condition $(1)$ is satisfied. You can thus apply Fubini's theorem and exchange the $\mathbb E$ and $\int$ symbols when computing the integral of $X_tY_t$.

Comment: Thanks! Without the condition of independence of $X$ and $Y$, do we still have the inequality in (*) part from  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?